# Dynamically Change Text if Text Status is =

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

just want to ask if it's possible for ReactJS to do this:

```
if(Response.text === 'Cancelled'){
   //Change text color to red
}else{
   //change to color green
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Serious lack of info in your question, but if you're asking about programmatically changing CSS then short answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** it's possible in all javascript frameworks.

to this case in ReactJS you have to do it:

```
<p style={{color: API_RESPONSE === 'Cancelled' ? 'red' : 'green'}}>
...
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

yep its possible.
if(text ==cancelled){
 write the css class for red button
}
else {
write the css class for green button
}
for this code,you should have to use the css classes for change the color

Answer (score 0):

It is possible

```
    <div style={{color: Response.text === 'Cancelled' ? 'color1' : 'color2'}}>
    //dosomthing
    </div>
```